# validation of input data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Goal:
Validate input data in my e-formulary.

Question:
What syntax code (dataannotations) do I need to ensure that data is int or decimal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are recieving your data from an input box, you can use a `TryParse` on your data. e.g.

```
decimal dec;
if(decimal.TryParse(YourInput.Text, out dec))
{
   // Valid Decimal
}
else { // Invalid }
```

...Same goes for an int, with `int.TryParse()`;

Answer (score 1):

The default model binder should handle validation automatically if you have specified your properties as int or decimal. You should get the following validation error if an incorrect value is entered:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}

The value 'i am a string' is invalid for MyProperty.
```

If you would like to do further validation such as only allowing certain ranges or formatting then you could use the [RangeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) or the [RegularExpressionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) attributes.

```
[RegularExpression(@"\d+", ErrorMessage="MyProperty must be an int.")]
public int MyProperty { get; set; }

[Range(typeof(Decimal), "20", "25")]
public decimal MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Comment: You can also use the `RangeAttribute` with integers. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding the question.  For data type validation, simply have the property on your model be of the desired type (int or decimal).